# Issue passing files from file input to JavaScript formData

Tags: javascript, file-io, fetch

I'm having a problem when I try to pass my file from an html input to js script.

Here's my html input:

```
echo "<td scope=\"col\"><input type=\"file\" id=\"newImage\" name=\"imageCategory\" onchange=\"changeImageCategory('" . $category["product_category_id"]."', '".$category["image_path"] ."')\">";
```

and that's my js function:

```
async function changeImageCategory(categoryId, oldPath){
    let formData = new FormData();
    //let newImage = document.getElementById('newImage');
     formData.append("imageCategory", newImage.files[0]);

    console.log(formData);
    await fetch('../PHP/requestUploadImageCategory.php?id='+encodeURI(categoryId)+'&oldPath='+encodeURI(oldPath),{
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }

    });
    await displayCategory();
}
```

I tried to console.log the "newImage.files[0]"

And I have almost the same function in my code that's working and returns the name of my file correctly in the console.log.

I've really tried everything can someone rescue me I'm very late on my project.
Thank you

I also copied my second function (this one is working!):

```
async function createCategory(){
    let newCategoryName = document.getElementById('newCategoryName').value;
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("NewImageCategory", NewImageCategory.files[0]);
    await fetch('../PHP/requestAddCategory.php?name='+encodeURI(newCategoryName),{
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    });
    document.getElementById("NewImageCategory").value = "";
    await displayCategory();
}
```

Comment: The key difference between the two functions seems to be in the second you you're doing `document.getElementById('newCategoryName').value`. Have you tried adding the .value accessor to the first function? `document.getElementById('newImage').value`

Comment: tank you for ur message, in the second document.getElementById('newCategoryName').value is for an text input. and yeah I tried  let newImage = document.getElementById('newImage');    and also tried                              let newImage = document.getElementById('newImage').value; nothing work